# free boundary of a p-harmonic function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

let $u$ be a p-harmonic function in $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$.

We already know that the set $\{u=0\}$ is locally a $C^{1,\alpha}$ hypersurface at the points where $\nabla u\neq 0$.

What can be said about the overall regularity of the set $\partial \{u\neq 0\}$.
this will also include the points where gradient of u is zero.